# Convert a list to a dict

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Im writing a small application i Angular2, and need a simple way to convert a list to a dict.

I have a list:

```
var list = ["foo", "bar"];
```

I want to convert the list to a dict like this:

```
var dict = {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"};
```

Whats the easiest way to do this using typescript, javascript, jQuery or Angular2?

Comment: Looking at that top answer, instead of `obj[v] = 0;`, you'd use `obj[v] = v;`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This is a duplicate, thanks for helping out.

Comment: `["foo", "bar"].reduce((acc, cur) => (acc[cur] = cur, acc), {})`

Answer (score 2):

Try with `Array#reduce`

```js
var list = ["foo", "bar"];
console.log(list.reduce((a,b)=> (a[b]=b , a), {}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let list = ["foo", "bar"];

        let dict = {};
        for (let i=0; i< list.length; i++ ) {
                dict[list[i]] = list[i];
        }
        console.log(dict);
```